# Error in the name while fetching it from the website

Tags: python, regex, utf-8, urllib

when i run the code and print deals, some the deals names are not correct like

```
respData = urllib.request.urlopen(
    'https://www.mcdelivery.com.pk/pk/browse/menu.html')

resp = respData.read().decode('utf-8')

link = re.findall(r'<ul class="secondary-menu">(.*?)</ul>', str(resp))
# URLS
Urls = re.findall("href=[\"\'](.*?)[\"\']", str(link))

# remove amp from the urls
Url1 = [re.sub(r'amp;', '', item) for item in Urls]
# menu
deals = re.findall(r'<span>(.*?)</span>', str(link))
print(deals)
```

code output:

```
['Deals', "\\\\xe2\\\\x98\\\\x85What\\\\\\'s New\\\\xe2\\\\x98\\\\x85", '\\\\xc3\\\\x80la carte & Value Meals', 'Crispy Chicken', 'Share Box', 'Happy Meals', 'Desserts', 'McCaf\\\\xc3\\\\xa9', 'Beverages', 'Side Lines', 'Snack Time']
```

`\\xe2\\x98\\x85What\\\'s New\\xe2\\x98\\x85` this should be `What's New` and This `\\xc3\\x80la carte & Value Meals` should be `la carte & value meals`.

Comment: The shown output doesn't make sense because "re.findall" returns a list which should be printed as list representation (with brackets, quotes,...).

Comment: `['Deals', "\\\\xe2\\\\x98\\\\x85What\\\\\\'s New\\\\xe2\\\\x98\\\\x85", '\\\\xc3\\\\x80la carte & Value Meals', 'Crispy Chicken', 'Share Box', 'Happy Meals', 'Desserts', 'McCaf\\\\xc3\\\\xa9', 'Beverages', 'Side Lines', 'Snack Time']` The output is this I want to remove the backslash and all the encoding from it

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to remove any non-utf8 char from the strings. Just add the following line after `deals = re.findall(...)`

```
deals = list(map(lambda line: line.decode('utf-8','ignore').encode("utf-8"), deals))
```

Comment: There is an error `in <lambda>
    deals = list(map(lambda line: line.decode(
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`